# Error: The 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine

Tags: asp.net, ms-office, oledb

Selecting data from an excel file over ASP.NET.

I continue to see this error.
Steps taken:

1. In VS 2008, set project build platform to x86.
2. Installed 2010 Office Data Connectivity component on the server machine.
3. Opened IIS 7, opened the application pool, enabled 32-bit applications.

Connection string looks like this:
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + targetFilePath + ";Extended Properties=Excel 14.0;"

Any other steps to be taken?

Comment: Last time I ran into this issue, it was a problem with bitness, ie. 32 vs 64 bit drivers

Comment: You're absolutely correct.  My systems admin installed the 64 byte version of the connectivity components while our application runs at 32 bits.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I ran into this issue, it was a problem with bitness, ie. 32 vs 64 bit drivers.  (Move comment to answer so you'd have an opportunity mark this issue as done & answered.)